# Exception thrown: read access violation this->pCurr was 0xDDDDDDDD

Tags: c++, exception, linked-list, destructor

I am a beginner and am working on linked list. I am trying to make a method that removes the current link of a list. I am getting an exception : read access violation this->pCurr was 0xDDDDDDDD.

This is what my code looks like (I removed some methods, such as adding links and left only those related to removal)

```
template <class T>
struct TNode {
    T val;
    TNode<T> *pNext;
};
template <class T>
class TList {
protected:
    TNode <T> *pFirst, *pLast, *pCurr, *pPrev, *pStop;
    int len; //lenght
    int pos;//where pCurr shows
public:
    //constructor
    TList() {
        pFirst = NULL;
        pLast = NULL;
        pCurr = NULL;
        pPrev = NULL;
        pStop = NULL;
        len = 0;
        pos = 0;
    }
    //destructor
    ~TList() {
        TNode<T> *tmp = pFirst;
        //if (tmp == pStop)
            //delete tmp;
        while (pFirst != pStop) {
            pFirst = pFirst->pNext;
            delete tmp;
            tmp = pFirst;
        }
    }
    //delete first link
    void DelFirst() {
        T res = pFirst->val;
        TNode<T> *tmp;
        tmp = pFirst;
        pFirst = pFirst->pNext;
        delete tmp;
        len--;
    }
    //delete current link
    void DelCurr() {
        if (pCurr == pFirst)
            DelFirst();
        else {
            TNode<T> *tmp = pCurr;
            pPrev->pNext = pCurr->pNext; // an exception is thrown on this line
            pCurr = pCurr->pNext;
            delete tmp;
            len--;
        }
    }
    //set pCurr to the beginning
    void Reset() {
        pCurr = pFirst;
        pPrev = pStop;
        pos = 0;
    }
    //go to the next link
    void GoNext() {
        //if (IsEnd()) throw - 1;
        //else {
            pPrev = pCurr;
            pCurr = pCurr->pNext;
            pos++;
        //}
    }
    //end check
    bool IsEnd() {
        return (pCurr == pStop);
    }
    //delete the whole list
    void DelList() {
        for (Reset(); !IsEnd(); GoNext()) {
            DelCurr();
        }
        DelCurr();
    }
};
```

Please tell me what this exception is related to and how to fix it.

Comment: In this line `pPrev->pNext = pCurr->pNext;` what do you think will happen if pCurr is null?

Comment: @theWiseBro Does this mean that the pointer does not point to anything and the list is empty? That is, I assign a pointer to anything and because of this an error? I'll try at the beginning of the method to add a list check for emptiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for null pointers everywhere

And in DelFirst() function, set the pCurr to the next, when it points on pFirst

```
void DelFirst()
{
    if (pFirst == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (pCurr == pFirst)
    {
        pCurr = pFirst->pNext;
    }
    T res = pFirst->val;
    TNode<T>* tmp;
    tmp = pFirst;
    pFirst = pFirst->pNext;
    delete tmp;
    len--;
}
```

Comment: I have a linked list, and the end of the list occurs when pCurr = pStop. Can I check on pStop and not NULL?

Comment: Could you explain why I need to install pCurr on the next when it points to pFirst? It helped, but I don’t quite understand how it works.

Comment: In your example code, pStop is set to NULL and remains so. So pStop is just an alias for NULL (so maybe the pStop variable is unnecessary?). And yes, you can also use it to check for NULL, until you won't use the pStop value for something else.

Comment: If you call DeleteFirst(), it will delete the first element from the list. In this case, if pCurr pointed on the pFirst (which is deleted), it will be a dangling pointer ~ pointer to a memory location, which has been released. After that, when you call DeleteCurr(), it's try to use pCurr, which is invalid